# Struggling to convert to json string

Tags: php, laravel

I've got a textbox that the user can enter details into it in a csv format. So they would enter something like

```
user 1,user1@email.com
user 2,user2@email.com
user 3,user3@email.com
```

The out put of that when I `dd(request('users'))` is this

```
user 1, user1@email.com\n
user 2, user2@email.com\n
user 3, user3@email.com
```

What I would like is to save it in a json format so that it can end up looking like this

```
[
    {
        "name": "user 1",
        "email": "user1@email.com"
    },
    {
        "name": "user 2",
        "email": "user2@email.com"
    },
    {
        "name": "user 3",
        "email": "user3@email.com"
    }
]
```

I'm struggling to get it to be like how I would like it. I've tried `json_encode(request('users'))` but I ended up with

```
""user 1, user1@email.com\nuser 2, user2@email.com\nuser 3, user3@email.com""
```

I also tried this

```
$replace = preg_replace('/\n+/', "\n", trim(request('users')));
$split = explode("\n",$replace);
$json = json_encode($split);
```

but I got this

```
"["user 1, user1@email.com","user 2, user2@email.com", "user 3, user3@email.com"]"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keys `name` and `email` you want in your result are not going to appear out of thin air, you need to *create* them.

Split the data into individual lines, loop over those lines.
Split each line into its two parts.
Create the necessary data structure, introduce the keys you want the data to be stored under at this point.
Encode the whole thing as JSON.

```
$data = 'user 1,user1@email.com
user 2,user2@email.com
user 3,user3@email.com';

$lines = explode("\n", $data);
$result = [];

foreach($lines as $line) {
  $parts = explode(',', $line);
  $result[] = ['name' => $parts[0], 'email' => $parts[1]];
}

echo json_encode($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `array_map` to map each line to a key-value pair created by using `array_combine`:

```
$array = array_map(function($line) {
    return array_combine(['name', 'email'], str_getcsv($line));
}, explode("\n", $request('users')));

$json = json_encode($array);

var_dump($json);
```

The result would be:

```
string(133) "[{"name":"user 1","email":"user1@email.com"},{"name":"user 2","email":"user2@email.com"},{"name":"user 3","email":"user3@email.com"}]"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$xx = "user 1, user1@email.com\nuser 2, user2@email.com\nuser 3, user3@email.com";
$xxx = explode("\n",$xx);
$res = [];
foreach($xxx as $y)
{
    $new = explode(',',$y);
    $res[] = [
        'name'  => $new[0],
        'email' => $new[1]
        ];
}

echo json_encode($res,true);


Output will be


[
   {
     "name":"user 1","email":" user1@email.com"
   },
   {
     "name":"user 2","email":" user2@email.com"
   },
   {
     "name":"user 3","email":" user3@email.com"
   }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$data = explode("\n", trim(request('users')));

$result = collect($data)->map(function ($row) {
    $columns = explode(',', $row);

    return [
        'name' => $columns[0] ?? null,
        'email' => $columns[1] ?? null
    ];
});
```